# same Int has different values in Swift, mysterious riddle

Tags: swift, random, integer, nslog

with this code :

```
let rand : Int = Int(arc4random())
NSLog("rand = %d %i %@ \(rand)",rand,rand,String(rand))
```

I get :

```
rand = -1954814774 -1954814774 2340152522 2340152522
```

why all 4 values are not the same ?

Comment: maybe linked to func arc4random() -> UInt32 but why ?

Comment: Maybe it has smth to do with signed vs unsigned? Int & Double are signed, the string interpretations are not

Comment: according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int Int is a signed integer value type.

Comment: "On 32-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int32, and on 64-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int64." so there 's probably a link with 32 / 64 bits but I still don't understand what's the value of rand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arc4random` generates an unsigned 32bit int. `Int` is probably 64 bit on your machine so you get the same number and it doesn't overflow. But `%i` and `%d` are *signed* 32-bit format specifiers. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) and [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). That's why you get a negative number when `arc4random` returns a number greater than 2^32-1, aka `Int32.max`.

For example, when 2340152522 is generated, you get `-1954814774` in the `%i` position because:

```
Int32(bitPattern: 2340152522) == -1954814774
```

On the other hand, converting an `Int` to `String` won't change the number. `Int` is a signed 64 bit integer.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks ! I understand I should not use %i and %d . Is it safe to use Int(arc4random()) or is it better to stick to a 32bit int ?

Comment: @Gogo123 you should use `Int.random(in: 0...10)`